# admin console log search using options since

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to filter my logs in the admin console for only recent entries.

I tried selecting the "Since:" option and putting in a date but it doesn't seem to work.

It seems to be filtering entries "until" the date I enter and not "since"?  Is this just mislabeled or does it only work in conjuction with the "Filter:" option that I left empty as I only want to filter by date?

If the "Since:" option functionality is in fact "until", then can anyone suggest a filter that would return entries after a specific date.